# My code is working but stops after 15 minutes how to make it run for infinite time?

Tags: python, pyautogui

it has no error works properly but stops after around 15 to 30 minutes my code is as follows:

```py
import pyautogui as pe
import time
print ("************Enter CTRL-C' to exit the program**")
try:
   pe.click(1915, 1070, 1, 3,'left')
   pe.hotkey ('win','q')
   pe.write('Microsoft Teams')
   pe.press ('enter')
   pe.getWindowsWithTitle ("Microsoft Teams")[0].maximize() 
   time.sleep (3)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   pass

try:
   while True:
      pe.moveTo (0,35,1)
      pe.moveTo (1116, 132, 1)
      time.sleep (10)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
   pass
```

Comment: what exactly this code does? :)

Comment: 15-30 minutes is a large window for failure. Can you collect a more accurate time to failure metric? How does the code stop. Does the program receive a KeyboardInterrupt, or is there some other uncaught error that leads to the code halting?

Comment: Remove the try/except blocks and see if it still returns no error.

Comment: If you're only catching KeyboardInterrupt, then either somehow KeyboardInterrupt is emitted or you should be able to see the info about the error when the program terminates.

Comment: Try setting the screensaver  to OFF, and set sleep to NEVER for both Charge on and off.